# unusual ternary operation

Tags: php, logic, ternary-operator, logical-operators

I was asked to perform this operation of ternary operator use:

```
$test='one';

echo $test == 'one' ? 'one' :  $test == 'two' ? 'two' : 'three';
```

Which prints two (checked using php).

I am still not sure about the logic for this. Please, can anybody tell me the logic for this.

Comment: oh my... my eyes... are burning.... it cannot be unseen...

Comment: It's not so bad. In other languages, this would be an idiom. In PHP, thanks to its poorly-chosen operator associativity, it's a trap.

Comment: @bobince did u tried it in other languages or u r just assuming this

Comment: C and most languages based on its syntax (C#, Java, JavaScript...) give `one`. Wiki (fairly, IMO) describes PHP's behaviour as “an unfortunate error in the language grammar”. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#PHP

Comment: i think most of us got it rite, sorry but could only choose 1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, the ? and : have equal precedence, so PHP will parse left to right evaluating each bit in turn:

```
echo ($test == 'one' ? 'one' :  $test == 'two') ? 'two' : 'three';
```

First `$test == 'one'` returns true, so the first parens have value 'one'. Now the second ternary is evaluated like this:

```
'one' /*returned by first ternary*/ ? 'two' : 'three'
```

'one' is true (a non-empty string), so 'two' is the final result.

Comment: +1 for brevity and clarity of explanation (a difficult combination)

Answer (score 7):

Basically interpreter evaluates this expression from left to right, so:

```
echo $test == 'one' ? 'one' :  $test == 'two' ? 'two' : 'three';
```

is interpreted as

```
echo ($test == 'one' ? 'one' :  $test == 'two') ? 'two' : 'three';
```

And the expression in paratheses evaluates to true, since both 'one' and 'two' are not null/o/other form of false.
So if it would look like:

```
echo $test == 'one' ? FALSE :  $test == 'two' ? 'two' : 'three';
```

It would print three. To make it work okay, you should forget about combining ternary operators, and use regular ifs/switch for more complicated logic, or at least use the brackets, for the interpreter to understand your logic, and not perform checking in standard LTR way:

```
echo $test == 'one' ? 'one' :  ($test == 'two' ? 'two' : ($test == 'three' ? 'three' : 'four'));

//etc... It's not the most understandable code... 

//You better use:
if($test == 'one')
    echo 'one';
else { //or elseif()
...
}

//Or:
switch($test) {
    case 'one':
        echo 'one';
        break;
    case 'two':
        echo 'two';
        break;
//and so on...
}
```

Comment: Exactly, I was about to post it, I found it in the php documentation. :)

Answer (score 5):

It works correctly when you use brackets:

```
<?
 $test='one';
 echo $test == 'one' ? 'one' :  ($test == 'two' ? 'two' : 'three');
```

I don't understand it 100% but without brackets, to the interpreter, the statement must look like this:

```
echo ($test == 'one' ? 'one' :  $test == 'two') ? 'two' : 'three';
```

the result of the first condition seems to be returned as the result of the whole ternary operation.

Answer (score 1):

PHP'S [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) says:

> **Note:** It is recommended that you **avoid "stacking" ternary expressions**. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious:
>
> Example #3 Non-obvious Ternary Behaviour
>
> ```
> <?php
> // on first glance, the following appears to output 'true'
> echo (true?'true':false?'t':'f');
>
> // however, the actual output of the above is 't'
> // this is because ternary expressions are evaluated from left to right
>
> // the following is a more obvious version of the same code as above
> echo ((true ? 'true' : false) ? 't' : 'f');
>
> // here, you can see that the first expression is evaluated to 'true', which
> // in turn evaluates to (bool)true, thus returning the true branch of the
> // second ternary expression.
> ?>
> ```

If you put parenthesis around the false statement, it prints `one`:

```
echo $test == 'one' ? 'one' :  ($test == 'two' ? 'two' : 'three');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is evaluated like this:

```
echo ($test == 'one' ? 'one' :  $test == 'two') ? 'two' : 'three';
```

($test == 'one' ? 'one' :  $test == 'two') is non-zero/null, so 'two' is logical output

if you want it to work correctly, write:

```
echo $test == 'one' ? 'one' :  ($test == 'two' ? 'two' : 'three');
```

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operators are executed in order of appearance so you really have:

```
echo ($test == 'one' ? 'one' :  $test == 'two') ? 'two' : 'three';
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested ternary operations are gross! The above explanation shows why.

Basically this is the logic:

```
is $test == 'one'

  if TRUE then echo 'one'

  else is $test == 'two'

      if TRUE then echo 'two'

      else echo three
```

Comment: I think you are on the right track and have the best explanation but your logic doesn't add up yet, as it is not outputting `one`

Comment: Filix Kling's explanation answers that question although it doesn't make sense why parenthesis are needed.