# Is there difference between ternary operator and if condition?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

Is there difference between ternary operator and if condition in php ?

if yes, kindly provide.

Comment: Can you show a concrete example?

Comment: cleary saying : no difference, this is just shortcut way

Comment: @King is it so?? i really did not know that.

Answer (score 12):

The ternary operator is an **operator**, so it forms an expression. So it will have a value that you can assign to a variable or use however you want. It is used for simple situations where a variable can take two possible values depending on a condition.

For example: `$status = $age > 18 ? 'adult' : 'child';`

Although possible, [you should not nest the ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#example-111).

The **control structure** `if` is something absolutely different. The only thing they have in common that both evaluate a condition (true/false). `if` is used to execute code fragments based on the result of that condition. You will find yourself using `if` most of the time (in fact, you can live without the ternary). In certain situations, it is less code and more readable if you replace certain types of `if`s with the ternary, like this one:

```
if ($age > 18) {
    $status = 'adult';
} else {
    $status = 'child';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I only use the ternary operator if it fits on one line. If it need to span, then it's time for the good old

```
 $value = ($a < 0) ? 'minus' : 'plus';
```

also you can see one interesting question how multiple ternary works :

### [unusual ternary operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658665/unusual-ternary-operation)

Comment: @diEcho Thanks. So final conclusion is, no difference between if condition and ternary operator ?

Comment: @Dinesh NO... nothing..this is called just a shortcut for if else

Comment: reference : http://www.aarongloege.com/blog/web-development/php/php-ternary-operator/

Comment: @diEcho: Thats wrong, the ternary operator and `if` has some very important differences. `?:` is an operator, `if` not. `?:` has a return value, `if` not. Very obvious: `$a = $b ? $c ? $d` is valid, `$a = if ($b) $c else $d;` is invalid.

Comment: @King why don't u post as an answer

Comment: @diEcho: bazmegakapa already wrote nearly the same. No need for a duplicate answer.

Comment: @King `$a = $b ? $c ? $d` is invalid. it must have `==`

Comment: @KIng either u r just confused, there is nothing which can be written in `ternary` but not in `if` `else` . understand..

Comment: @diEcho: Hehe, no, the assignment is correct, but it must be `:` instead of the second `?` :D (`$a = $b ? $c : $d;`). // You can write a semantic identical version with `if`, but they don't make the constructs identical. For example there are _very_ _much_ things, that must be written with `if`, because its not possible with `?:`.

Comment: `$a = $b ? $c : $d;` what it returns btw??

Comment: This assigns `$c` to `$a`, if `$b` is `true`, `$d` else.

Comment: $a=2;
what about this, you are stick with `true` & `false` only `$b=1;
$c=5;
$d=8;

$a = $b ? $c : $d;

var_dump($a);`

Comment: @diEcho var_dumps($a) returns 5int(5)

Comment: @KingCrunch if PHP supports the comma operator, I think _anything_ could be written with a ternary that could be written with an `if/else`.

Comment: @Carson In PHP you cannot combine expression with a comma like you could in C (the only exception I can think of is in `for` loops).

Comment: @diEcho: I "stick with `true` and `false`", because _everything_ in PHP can (and will) be casted into a boolean. In your examle: `(($b = 1) === 1) == true`. If you use anything else than a boolean expression there, PHP doesn't care and cast it.

Answer (score 1):

If statements are faster than ternary, but in most cases it doesn't matter.

[Here](http://fabien.potencier.org/the-php-ternary-operator-fast-or-not.html) is a post on the performance of If statements vs ternary.
Summary: It's basically the same unless you are evaluating large objects because ternary copies the objects being evaluated. This was using PHP 5.3 I'm not sure if it has been changed in current versions.

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator can do anything that an if/else statement can. In some cases it can provide brevity and expressiveness, but beware: it is easily abused.

One thing I like it for is checking for null:

```
$foo = (is_null($bar)) ? 0 : $bar->someNumber();
```

If my PHP memory serves me correctly, then it can also be used on an lvalue:

```
((is_null($foo)) ? $bar : $foo) = $quux;
```

It can be easily overdone though, such as in this C++ example, where it is used in place of loops and if/else statements:

```
while( ( ! printingStars) ?
     ( ( ! reachedMax) ?
       ( ( ++numberOfStars == n - 1) && (reachedMax = 1) )
       : --numberOfStars ), printingStars = 1, starsLeft = numberOfStars
     : ( ( ! starsLeft ) ?
         printingStars = 0, (std::cout<< std::endl), 1
         : --starsLeft, (std::cout<< "*"), 1 ) );
```

Use with caution.

Comment: `$foo == null` can not be trusted. You should use `is_null($foo)` instead.

Comment: I prefer `is_null()`, but some argue, that `$foo === null` is slightly faster (and safe in contrast to `==`).

Comment: @KingCrunch Yes, that's another fine approach. I prefer `is_null()` myself, it adds a bit of readability to me (but that's a personal preference only).

Comment: `==`/`===` bugs, I have found, are quite difficult to chase down.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another point of view: Performance.

A while ago I noticed that the ternary operator is faster than an if(). I don't know if this still applies to the latest versions of PHP.

< wild guess >
The reason may be that an if() allows more flexibility like using code blocks (`{ }`). A ternary operator basically is just testing an expression and grabbing a value depending on the result of the test.

Going back into my Assembler-days I'd say that an if() has to jump in memory and, therefore, takes a bit more time to do things.
< /wild guess >

However, this may be become noticeable only if the code is executed a decent number (1k+) of times.

Comment: This is micro-optimization. Never switch an `if` into a ternary **because of performance**.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: I totally agree. This question is about the difference between these two and I thought I should mention it nonetheless.

Answer (score -1):

There is a big difference in maintenance, if you use none trivial logic.

If you have a difficult problem you need under circumstances much more time, to sove it, as if you have an 'if ... then' in your code. And be sure: it's happen!

The time is not a friend of ternary operator. Fast to write, but not fast to understand, if the years gone!