# Can someone explain what this statement means

Tags: jquery, height

I have come across this use of operators before and I know its a compressed if statement but can someone tell me in layman's terms exactly what this means.

```
$("#portfolio-id").height($("#portfolio-id").height() > h-72 ? divHeights-72 : h-72);
```

I don't even know what it is called to google it.
Does anyone have any links I can go to and find the answer myself?

Thanks very much for the help

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989982/is-there-difference-between-ternary-operator-and-if-condition (this one is for PHP but they work the same way)

Comment: Here's a link to the height() function in the jQuery docs http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var newHeight;
if ($("#portfolio-id").height() > h-72)
{
  newHeight = divHeights-72;
}
else
{
  newHeight = h - 72;
}
$("#portfolio-id").height(newHeight);
```

Unknown what h is or divHeights

Answer (score 1):

It means:

```
set the height of the element with id portfolio-id to the following value:
    if the height of the element with id portfolio-id is greater than h-72 then
        the value is divHeights-72
    else
        the value is h-72
```

This operator is usually called the *ternary operator*, and the general form is

```
testThisCondition ? returnThisIfTrue : returnThisIfFalse;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sets the new height for something with `id="portfolio-id"`. If it is bigger than `h-72` then it is set to `divheights-72;` else, it is set to `h-72`

It is called a ternary statement

Answer (score 1):

if the height of `#portfolio-id` is greater then `h -72` then set portfolio height to `divHeights -72` else set it to `h-72`

here is an msdn article explaining **ternary operators**:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

and here is another one from about.com

http://javascript.about.com/od/byexample/a/ternary-example.htm

Answer (score 1):

It's the ternary operator.  It works like

`var x = condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse;`

It's basically shorthand for writing an if/else statement.

Answer (score 1):

**divHeights** and **h** are some variables that were declared. The statement is using ternary if else, to determine what the new height of #portfolio-id is going to be.

```
//variable declarations
divHeights = x;
h = y;

//$("#portfolio-id").height() > h-72 ? divHeights-72 : h-72 is equivalent to the below code
if($("#portfolio-id").height() > h-72){
     newHeight = divHeights-72;
} else {
      newHeight =  h-72;
}

$("#portfolio-id").height(newHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#portfolio-id").height(              // sets #portfolio-id's height to...
   $("#portfolio-id").height() > h-72 ? //    if its current height is greater than h-72...
       divHeights-72                    //       then divHeights-72
     : h-72                             //       else h-72
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be somewhere value in h is assigned.

Suppose your h = 100;

now you are checking the height of "#portfolio-id" objects .

if($("#portfolio-id").height() > h-72)
than assign $("#portfolio-id").height =  divHeights-72 
else 
assign $("#portfolio-id").height =  divHeights-72 h-72

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#portfolio-id").height($("#portfolio-id").height() > h-72 ? divHeights-72 : h-72);

|               boolean check                               |  | if true|    |if false|
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called [Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (or ternary operator)

What that code is doing is:

```
var currentHeight = $("#portfolio-id").height(), newHeight = currentHeight; 
if (currentHeight > h-72) {            // if current height is greater than h - 72, use divHeights - 72
    newHeight = divHeights - 72;
} else {                               // otherwise use h - 72
    newHeight = h - 72;
}
$("#portfolio-id").height(newHeight);
```

What it should be doing (imo) is:

```
$("#portfolio-id").height(function(i, height) {
    if (height > h - 72) {
        return divHeights - 72;
    } else { 
        return h - 72;
    }
});
```

This uses the 2nd version of the [height function](http://api.jquery.com/height/)